# Error with express-session when user login in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, express-session

So basically in this code is only registration and login forms and it worked very well until I added session to it.

The problem is when user registers, it logs in console registered user's info, it is ok, but when user gets back to login page and refreshes page, console logs the information that logged when user registered and also session does not works, I am 100% sure that this is session problem, but I can not configure what it is, here is the code (don't pay attention to 'Friends' model it is for future purposes, and I also tested without that block of code and it worked so problem is not there)

```
   const http = require('http');
   const express = require('express');
   const socketIO = require('socket.io');
   const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   const multer = require('multer');
   const consolidate = require('consolidate');
   const session = require('express-session');

  const app = express();
  const server = http.Server(app);
  const io = socketIO(server);
  app.use(session({secret: 'zazagelovidzudzua', resave: false,                               
  saveUninitialized: true}))
  app.engine('html', consolidate.mustache);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.use(multer().array());
  app.use(express.static('public'));

  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const connectionUri = 'mongodb://localhost/my_database';
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

  mongoose
    .connect(connectionUri, {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Connection to database established');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('MongoDB connection error:', error.message);
      process.exit(-1);
    });


  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    friends: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Friends'}]
  });

  const Friend = new Schema({
    name: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    age: Number,
    address: String
  })

  const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
  const Friends = mongoose.model('Friends', Friend)
    var ses;

  app.get( '/', (req, res) => {
            res.render('mainpage');
    });

  app.get('/reg', (req, res) => {
      res.render('reg');
    });

  app.post(
    '/reeg',
    async (req,res) => {
      try {
  const username = req.body.username
  const password = req.body.password
  const email = req.body.email
  const user = await User.create({username, password, email});
  console.log('Created user:', user);
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '\\views\\mainpage.html')
      }
      catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
      }
    });

  app.post('/login', 
    async (req,res) => {
      ses = req.session

  const {username, password} = req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({username, password}).select('-            
  password').lean();
        if(!user) {
          res.send('User: ' + username +' not registered');
          return;
        }
        ses.user = user
        res.redirect('/dash')
        return res.status(200);




    });

    app.get('/dash',
    async (req,res) =>{

      try{
        if(!ses.user){
        res.status(401).send('login first please!')
        res.status(200)
        res.send('hi' + ses.user.username)
       }
      }

      catch(error){
  console.log(error.message)
      }


  })



  server.listen('8080');
```

pic when i refresh page after i register [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha7Jc.jpg)

Comment: you can check the connection and events with GUI client https://firecamp.app

Comment: i am not using GUI but later i think i will use mlab

Comment: FC is GUI client for SocketIO and WS.

Comment: oh, i thought u had meant Mongoose, okay thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error at

```
return res.status(200);

ses.user = user
```

You send status 200 to user, but you also `return`, that mean function not run continue, that make `ses.user = user` is unreachable (on VS Code, that line will be blur, detect it cannot be reachable).

My hint for you don't create variable `ses`, because `express-session` will create `session` in req for each user, but `ses` is used common for your server Node.JS, that mean all users use only this var `ses`. You should use `req.session` for each request.

Your code should be:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const consolidate = require('consolidate');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = socketIO(server);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'zazagelovidzudzua', resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
app.engine('html', consolidate.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer().array());
app.use(express.static('public'));

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectionUri = 'mongodb://localhost/my_database';
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose
    .connect(connectionUri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection to database established');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('MongoDB connection error:', error.message);
        process.exit(-1);
    });


const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    friends: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Friends' }]
});

const Friend = new Schema({
    name: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    age: Number,
    address: String
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
const Friends = mongoose.model('Friends', Friend)
// var ses; // don't create this var

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('mainpage');
});

app.get('/reg', (req, res) => {
    res.render('reg');
});

app.post(
    '/reeg',
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const username = req.body.username
            const password = req.body.password
            const email = req.body.email
            const user = await User.create({ username, password, email });
            console.log('Created user:', user);
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/mainpage.html')
        }
        catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error.message);
        }
    });

app.post('/login',
    async (req, res) => {
        ses = req.session
        try {
            const { username, password } = req.body;
            const user = await User.findOne({ username, password }).select('-password').lean();
            if (!user) {
                res.send('User: ' + username + ' not registered');
                return;
            }
            // ses.user = user
            req.session.user = user; // assign direct data to session for req

            return res.status(200).send('Session ID: ' + req.sessionID);

            // ses.user = user // unreachable statement
        }
        catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error.message);
        }
    });

app.get('/dash',
    async (req, res) => {
        // if (!ses.user) {
        if (!req.session.user) {
                res.status(401).send('login first please!')
        }
        res.status(200)
        // res.send('hi' + ses.user.username)
        res.send({
            sessionID: req.sessionID,
            message: 'Hi ' + req.session.user.username
        })
    })


server.listen('8080');
```

Comment: please check the code again i edited it,  but when i tried old code it still logs again
also when i tried this edited code (my code) it only showed can not get dash 
so let me try your code and i will tell u if it works

Comment: it shows me Session ID: 4q7bKy3DoonVcptAzzpidQkpNpmbKtD0 but in 'login' route not in 'dash' route

Comment: {"sessionID":"SlUS_q4CQyeWLbPgyOeuNKo0W5M_ytxC","message":"Hi george"}

Comment: oh i did not paid attention to res.send() sorry

Comment: it show me this error after i log in , but it still logs in anyway

(node:4900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)
(node:4900) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: and (node:4900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't set headers after the
y are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\tuna\Desktop\Xga\node_modules\express\lib
\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\tuna\Desktop\Xga\node_modules\express\lib\r
esponse.js:170:12)
    at app.post (C:\Users\tuna\Desktop\Xga\proj.js:100:29)
    at <anonymous>

Comment: @codR, OK :), thanks for your efforts with my solution